# SQLite DATETIME (in Julian/Real/Double) column with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, datetime-format

I have an existing SQLite database that I am calling with Entity Framework Codefirst. The dates are entered into SQLite (by a non c# code) as double (Julian or sometimes called real). I cannot read when I try to retrieve it with EF. I've tried to change the ConnectionString (at app.config) to datetimeformat= Ticks, CurrentCulture etc. to no avail. Anybody knows a different datetimeformat to read datetime format from double ? If no solution exists, I will store the date-time as long (Ticks) in SQLite. Help, if any,  will be appreciated and will avoid this workaround.

Comment: You can always use one of the sqlite [date and time functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) to convert from Julian day to the desired format.

Comment: Yeah. I noticed. Probably the easiest way is to use something like "datetime(1560199025, 'unixepoch')" as SQLite statement when writing and then when reading back by EF setting the datetimeformat=UnixEpoch at connectionstring. I'll try and see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is the solution I came up with:
I was using a non-c# code as COM DLL (called from .NET) and writing the SQLite DateTime fields at COM object in double (OLE Automation date). All was fine, until I tried to read the DateTime field back from .NET by Entity Framework. I've tried to change the ConnectionString (at app.config) to no avail. There seems to be no option at EF to read datetime fields by converting from OA date. The work-arounds are:
1- Use UnixEpoch,but it limits you < 1970.
2- Use Ticks
3- Use "plain old" String. 
I have opted for String, meaning I convert DateTime to String and pass it to COM. EF can read String data in SQLite fields marked as DateTime, without the need to identify the datetime format at ConnectionString.
This was the simplest solution for me, but I could have used Ticks as well (converting DT to Ticks (long) first at C# before passing to the COM and then use datetimeformat=Ticks at ConnectionString). I don't have overhead in writing string possibly because my date set is not that massive.